# Cucumber-JVM 3 - Convert DataTable to single object using asMap()

Tags: java, datatable, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

In `cucumber-jvm 3.x.x`, I want to convert a datatable with only 2 columns to a single object. This used to be automatic in `2.x.x` but has since been removed with the new major version.

**Code:**

```
// Feature
Scenario: Scan Barcode
    Given I Am At The Login Page
    When I Log In As Valid User
        | group    | gpao     |
        | username | svgpao1  |
        | password | REDACTED |

// Stepdef
@When("I Log In As Valid User")
public void I_Log_In_As_Valid_User(User user) throws Throwable {
    Selenium.enterText(driver, user.getUsername(), "username");
    Selenium.enterText(driver, user.getPassword(), "password");
    Selenium.clickElement(driver, "sign.in");
    LOGGER.debug("User Group=" + user.getGroup());
}

// Configurer
registry.defineDataTableType(new DataTableType(User.class, new TableTransformer<User>() {
    @Override
    public User transform(DataTable dataTable) throws Throwable {
        Map<String, String> map = dataTable.asMap(String.class, String.class);
        return new User(map);
    }
}));

// User - constructor
public User(Map<String, String> map) {
    this.group = map.get("group");
    this.username = map.get("username");
    this.password = map.get("password");
}
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
cucumber.runtime.CucumberException: Could not convert arguments for step [I Log In As Valid User] defined at 'jcucumberng.project.stepdefs.EnterPacketDetailsSteps.I_Log_In_As_Valid_User(User) in file:/Z:/workspace/java/jcucumberng-framework/target/test-classes/'.
The details are in the stacktrace below.
        at cucumber.runtime.PickleStepDefinitionMatch.couldNotConvertArguments(PickleStepDefinitionMatch.java:69)
        at cucumber.runtime.PickleStepDefinitionMatch.runStep(PickleStepDefinitionMatch.java:46)
        at cucumber.runner.TestStep.executeStep(TestStep.java:55)
        at cucumber.runner.TestStep.run(TestStep.java:42)
        at cucumber.runner.PickleStepTestStep.run(PickleStepTestStep.java:53)
        at cucumber.runner.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:47)
        at cucumber.runner.Runner.runPickle(Runner.java:44)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.PickleRunners$NoStepDescriptions.run(PickleRunners.java:140)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:68)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.runChild(FeatureRunner.java:23)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at cucumber.runtime.junit.FeatureRunner.run(FeatureRunner.java:73)
        at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:98)
        at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber.runChild(Cucumber.java:55)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber$1.evaluate(Cucumber.java:107)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:365)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:273)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:238)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:159)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:383)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:344)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:125)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:417)
Caused by: io.cucumber.datatable.CucumberDataTableException: 'jcucumberng.project.domain.User' could not transform
      | group    | gpao     |
      | username | svgpao1  |
      | password | REDACTED |
```

Comment: I'm afraid I can't see anything wrong with your solution :(
Try to convert the DataTable in the step definition, rather than using the registry?

Comment: U might need to add '@Transpose' annotation to step def, as ur datatable is switched... maybe this works

Comment: Hi @Grasshopper, can you put a quick snippet for `@Transpose` as answer and I'll try first thing in the morn.

Comment: Hi @Niel, sadly cucumber now requires a registry to use datatables since the v3 upgrade. The transition has been rough due to the removal of the automatic conversion.

Comment: This is my [cheatsheet](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2014/06/30/cucumber-data-tables)

Comment: Hi @Mike, as mentioned, this no longer works for v3 of cucumber for Java. DataTables now need to be registered for a type. See official release announcement [here](https://cucumber.io/blog/2018/05/19/announcing-cucumber-jvm-3-0-0).

Comment: Ah. I sorry.  I guess I'll have to look into it too. But not tonight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to also modify the transform method in addition to `@Transpose`.

```
public User transform(DataTable dataTable) throws Throwable {
    return new User(dataTable.asMaps().get(0));
}

@When("I Log In As Valid User")
public void I_Log_In_As_Valid_User(@Transpose SilverUser user) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(user);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works! Though I believe `asMap()` may be buggy then as it is supposed to do this by default.

Comment: asMap() will create entries for map with the key as the first column and the custom object for value of the remaining columns. This is what the docs mention. Not sure if this implementation has been changed in latest.

Comment: Confirmed with the developer [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/1434), that `asMap()` right now is as intended to avoid confusion with the orientation of "perfect square" tables. Above solution is correct. Thanks again!