# cucumber-jvm version 3 substitute design pattern for simple table to Map<String,String> operation

Tags: java, design-patterns, cucumber-jvm

I was exploring the new [io.cucumber.datatable.DataTable](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/datatable) support introduced in cucumber-jvm:3.0.0.  I have cucumber-jvm:3.0.2 installed.

My existing cucumber-jvm:2.4.0 project makes use of a simple design pattern where I pass a table into a step whose last parameter has type Map. This behaviour is no longer supported in version 3.

So I created a test case to model an alternative to this design pattern.  It works, but the Map that is returned is unmodifiable.  I worked around it but two questions:

1. Why is the returned map immutable? Am I overlooking an important design principle?
2. Is there a simpler way to accomplish my basic goal of finding a substitute design pattern?

Here is the code:

```
# h/t to https://github.com/cucumber/datatable-java/edit/master/datatable/src/test/java/io/cucumber/datatable/DataTableTypeRegistryTableConverterTest.java
Feature: Test simple DataTable converters  

  @simple_no_header_map_string_string
  Scenario: Convert a two column table to a Map
    Given a basic street address
      | streetAddress | 333 W Camden St |
      | cityName      | Baltimore       |
      | stateName     | MD              |
      | postalCode    | 21201           |
    When I specify Country "US"
    Then I can print the complete address 


package some.org.stuff.cucumberjvm302testbed;

import cucumber.api.java.en.Given;
import cucumber.api.java.en.Then;
import cucumber.api.java.en.When;

import io.cucumber.datatable.DataTable;
import io.cucumber.datatable.DataTable.TableConverter;
import io.cucumber.datatable.DataTableTypeRegistry;
import io.cucumber.datatable.DataTableTypeRegistryTableConverter;
import io.cucumber.datatable.TypeReference;

import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

public class Cucumber302TestBedSteps {

    private Map<String,String> addressMap;

    private final DataTableTypeRegistry registry = new DataTableTypeRegistry(Locale.ENGLISH);
    private final TableConverter converter = new DataTableTypeRegistryTableConverter(registry);
    private static final Type MAP_OF_STRING_TO_STRING = new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {
    }.getType();

    @Given("^a basic street address$")
    public void aBasicStreetAddress(DataTable datatable) {
        //Here is the workaround to make addressMap mutable
        addressMap = new HashMap<String,String>(converter.convert(datatable, MAP_OF_STRING_TO_STRING)); 
    }

    @When("^I specify Country \"(.+)\"$")
    public void iSpecifyCountry(String inputCountry) {
        addressMap.put("country", inputCountry);
    }

    @Then("^I can print the complete address$")
    public void iCanPrintTheCompleteAddress() {
        System.out.println("\n\t" + addressMap.get("streetAddress"));
        System.out.println("\t" + addressMap.get("cityName"));
        System.out.println("\t" + addressMap.get("stateName"));
        System.out.println("\t" + addressMap.get("postalCode"));
        System.out.println("\t" + addressMap.get("country") + "\n");
    }
}
```

I looked at [Cucumber-JVM 3 - Convert DataTable to single object using asMap()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51839707/cucumber-jvm-3-convert-datatable-to-single-object-using-asmap#comment90656324_51839707). I did implement that solution but I have some junior testers so I was looking for something simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may find this pattern to be a bit more to your liking:

```
private final Map<String,String> addressMap = new HashMap<>();

@Given("^a basic street address$")
public void aBasicStreetAddress(Map<String,String> address) {
    addressMap.putAll(address);
}

@When("^I specify Country \"(.+)\"$")
public void iSpecifyCountry(String inputCountry) {
    addressMap.put("country", inputCountry);
}

@Then("^I can print the complete address$")
public void iCanPrintTheCompleteAddress() {
    System.out.println("\n\t" + addressMap.get("streetAddress"));
    System.out.println("\t" + addressMap.get("cityName"));
    System.out.println("\t" + addressMap.get("stateName"));
    System.out.println("\t" + addressMap.get("postalCode"));
    System.out.println("\t" + addressMap.get("country") + "\n");
}
```

Rather then setting the addressMap in the given step we define it as an empty map first. This ensures that there is always a sensible default present. This makes steps more flexible because they can now be used in any order and multiple times. Admittedly of little value in this specific scenario but in general quite usefull.

Then in the given step we set the last parameter to `Map<String,String> address`. Cucumber will transform the `DataTable` into a map. We use `.putAll` to copy all fields from the `address` into the `addressMap`.

The `address` is immutable to prevent modification of the original input by methods with side effects. This is a useful mechanism when the original input is used later to make assertions. Unless the object was explicitly copied you can rely on the fact that it was not modified. This makes code easier to read.

> My existing cucumber-jvm:2.4.0 project makes use of a simple design pattern where I pass a table into a step whose last parameter has type Map. This behaviour is no longer supported in version 3.

This behavior is still supported. What made you think it wasn't?

> private final DataTableTypeRegistry registry = new DataTableTypeRegistry(Locale.ENGLISH);
>      private final TableConverter converter = new DataTableTypeRegistryTableConverter(registry);
>      private static final Type MAP_OF_STRING_TO_STRING = new TypeReference>() {
>       }.getType();

You don't need this here. Have a look at the [TypeRegistryConfigurer](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/examples/java-calculator/src/test/java/cucumber/examples/java/calculator/ParameterTypes.java). Though keep in mind that Maps and Lists of basic types have build in support.

Comment: Thank you. When I first started looking at V3, I tried a test run with the simple map and it failed. I, therefore (wrongly), concluded that dropping XStream had dropped the support for basic types.  But running just now under my final config, the basic Map and List support are working. So something must have been wrong in my first test configuration (now long gone).  Thanks again for setting me straight.

Comment: You're welcome. If you want to help out https://github.com/cucumber/docs.cucumber.io could use some love. :D